# Correct application of RMSE and MAE

Tags: model-evaluation, mse, metric, rms

I have ~ 120 different datasets (different scales, sample size etc) and for each dataset, I predict ONE statistical parameter (doesn't matter what for my question) with different methods. To compare the different methods I use RMSE and MAE across the different datasets. 
I.e. if $m$ is the method than the RMSE is calculated in the following manner:

$RMSE_m = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i\in D}(\hat{y}_{im}-y_i)^2}$

where $D$ are the datasets and $n$ the number of datasets.
Is this approach suitable to evaluated between different methods $m$ or did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to say that method 1 (say a neural net) has better performance than method 2 (say random forest) across the 120 different data sets?

Comment: @Dave I’m not using any Machine Learning methods, I’m predicting e.g the variance using a own method which mainly consists out of integrations. But I don’t think that this plays a role does it ?